# Replacing JPanel with JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, addition

I have a class that extends JFrame, and it has a BorderLayout. It has two private instance variables of type JPanel. They represent panels of buttons and are called flipButton and confidenceButtons. When you click on the button, the panel of buttons is replaced by the other panel of buttons. That is, if you click on a button in flipButton, flipButton is replaced by confidenceButtons. I tried to do it like this:

```
  private class FlipListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      remove(flipButton); 
      add(confidenceButtons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      validate();
      ...
    }
  } 
  private class ColorListener implements ActionListener{
    ...
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      ...
      remove(confidenceButtons); 
      add(flipButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      validate();
    }
  }
```

The buttons in flipButton have FlipListeners and the ones in confidenceButtons have ColorListeners. When the program is run, clicking on a button will remove the panel, but nothing is added to replace it. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

CardLayout turned out to be a simple and easy solution. It turns out that the above code does work; the problem was a typo in another section of my code. >.< However, I've always had trouble using these methods, and CardLayout, I find, simplifies it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

[image: Game view]  [image: High Scores view]

Comment: Also my first thought. Cardlayout is designed for this use case si it's the best maintainable choice.

Answer (score 5):

revalidate() + repaint() should be trick, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390240/dynamic-generation-of-buttons-in-java/6395105#6395105)

EDIT:

feel that you have got problem with that, examples for that [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/ComponentListenerandComponentEvent.htm) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Therevalidatemethodtodynamicallyupdatethe.htm) and again [example by trashgod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812002/removeall-not-removing-at-next-validate/5812981#5812981), feel free to built your question based on code again

another way is look at excelent example added by Andrew Thompson :-) +1

Comment: I looked at the example but don't quite understand. Why is repaint necessary since I'm not using Graphics? Would I call all three methods on confidenceButtons? The example looks very specific and I do not really know how to adapt it to my code.

Comment: +1 See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812002/removeall-not-removing-at-next-validate/5812981#5812981).

Comment: @Shelley example is specific avourt revalidate + validate + repaint, back to questin about repaint(), in most cases GUI works correctly and doesn't required for repaint(); hmmm and there isn't exists any Swing tutorial or detailed describtions about that :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I tried this: 

      all.remove(flipButton); 
      all.add(confidenceButtons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      all.validate();
      all.revalidate();
      all.repaint();

where all is a JPanel with a borderlayout that contains everything. I know something is wrong... but what should I type to make it right?

Comment: @Shelley could you translate your question to the code, looks like as link posted by trashgod is best base for that, then just edit your question

Comment: @mKorbel Could you please give me a snippet of code that I might try with my program? I am lost as to what methods I am supposed to call etc. and where.

Answer (score 1):

try using getContentPane() to call remove() ,add() methods ect..:

```
getContentPane().remove(flipButton); 
getContentPane().add(confidenceButtons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);   
getContentPane().revalidate();
getContentPane().repaint();
```

Edit:
this code bellow work for me:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Frame extends JFrame {
JPanel flipButton =new JPanel();
JPanel confidenceButtons =new JPanel();



    public Frame() throws HeadlessException {
    super();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JButton b1=new JButton("flip");
    b1.addActionListener(new FlipListener());
    flipButton.add(b1);

    JButton b2=new JButton("color");
    b2.addActionListener(new ColorListener());
    confidenceButtons.add(b2);
    this.getContentPane().add(flipButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.setSize(250,250);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);

}
    private class FlipListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          remove(flipButton); 
          add(confidenceButtons,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
          validate();
          repaint();

        }
      } 
      private class ColorListener implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

          remove(confidenceButtons); 
          add(flipButton,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
          validate();
          repaint();
        }
      }
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();

    }

}
```

Comment: if you can post your complete JFrame class code i can try fixing it. maybe try using another layout instead of Borederlayout. b/c BorderLayout sometimes causes some strange behavior

Comment: I think it should not matter. I have read that the add, remove etc methods automatically add to the content pane when called alone, so getContentPane() is unnecessary.

Comment: I tried using CardLayout and it works perfectly now (CardLayout turned out to be an easy solution). Thank you for your help.

Comment: i have edit my answer with a code portion i wrote and tested which works fine for me. is that what you need?

Comment: I just found a typo in my code, of all things, that might have been causing the problems I had with this earlier. Having fixed that, this does work now. Thank you!