# How to add components to JFrame once it's visible without having to resize it?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, resize

I have a program where I have a `JFrame` with a `JButton` in it. When the user clicks the `JButton`, all `Components` of the `JFrame` are removed, and a `JPanel` with red background is added to it.

When I click the `JButton`, that red `JPanel` does not become visible unless I resize the `JFrame` (I am using Windows 7). Is there a way to achieve what I want without having to manually resize the `JFrame`?

Here is a part of the code I am using:

```
public class Demo implements ActionListener{
    public static void main(String args[]){
           ...............
        button.addActionListener(this); //'button' is an object of Jbutton class.
        frame.setVisible(true); //'frame' is an object of JFrame class.
        ............
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        frame.removeAllComponents();
        frame.add(panel1); //panel1 is an object of Jpanel class with red  background.

        /* Here is where my problem lies.
           panel1 is not visible to me unless I manually resize the JFrame. */
    }
}
```

Comment: In the panel1 constructor, are u calling .pack() on the jFrame?

Comment: Oddly enough, I found that this is actually more correct given the circumstances.

Comment: Consider using a `CardLayout`.  See [E.G.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665156/calling-awt-frame-methods-from-subclass/5786005#5786005).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For removing (and then, for example, add new JComponents) [JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) from [JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) or from [top-level containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) you have to call, only once and on the end of the action:

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

And if you only resize or change JComponents:

```
validate();
repaint();
```

Comment: is a `repaint()` really necessary?

Comment: @little bunny foo foo  for correct work for LayoutManager yes, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390240/dynamic-generation-of-buttons-in-java/6395105#6395105

Comment: could you see my post? I would like for your opinion on my findings. :)

Comment: Just use revalidate() all the time. There is no need to make a distinction between adding/removing and changing, The way I look at it is that invoking revalidate() is to make sure the layout manager is invoked and changing the size of a component may affect the layout.

Comment: It's impossible to invoke `revalidate()` on a top-level container. As suggested by @Andrew Thompson, I think using `CardLayout` is more appropriate in this situation.

Comment: I am changing the size of components and validate() is not working.  revalidate() is working though. tks

Answer (score 5):

For me, this was a bit of an oddity. As it turned out, invoking [`remove(Component comp)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29), adding the new `JPanel`, and then invoking [`pack()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) worked for me.

```
public class Demo{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                frame.remove(panel);

                final JPanel redPanel = new JPanel(){

                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                        return new Dimension(200, 200);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                        Graphics g2 = g.create();

                        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

                        g2.dispose();
                    }
                };

                frame.add(redPanel);
                frame.pack();
            }
        });

        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**BEFORE PRESSING THE BUTTON**

[image]

**AFTER PRESSING THE BUTTON**

[image]

**ODDITIES**

1. Invoking [`removeAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll%28%29) actually caused the GUI to freeze. It seems that this event has occurred [before](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/86207-swing-is-giving-me-trouble/). This occurred even after I attempted to remove the action listener prior to removal of all components.
2. I did not need to invoke any of the validate methods, or even repaint the GUI.

Comment: Invoking *pack()* more than once is not good programmatically speaking at all, as seen in my post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604487/changing-on-screen-component-for-jframe-is-clunky-and-messy-java

Calling *pack()* creates a race condition in which components being allocated into memory and being displayed on screen do not happen in a linear order like you may think. If you want to remove something then use **CardLayout** and include two panes, one with and one without the certain component and then flip to the panes when need be. **You should only call pack() once.**

Answer (score -1):

you have to force a repaint() in the frame so the frame have to repaint itself.