# Changing on-screen component for JFrame is clunky and messy

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, refresh, pack

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem so far through research and may in fact be a problem with **JFrame** as a whole.

Like any desktop application, most times the clicking of a button or "object" presents an action of changing what is currently being displayed. So for example, if I currently have an "input form" on the **display frame** and then the user clicks a button labeled "*submit*," the screen changes to a congratulations screen saying "*your form has correctly been submitted*," where all previous elements of the form are no longer showing.

Now in most cases, we set up a **JFrame** like so:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Where *panel* is a **JPanel** that contains all the primary display objects and layouts at the current time.

Alright this is great, but if we want to change the content pane to introduce a new screen we would do something of the following:

```
frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
frame.getContentPane().add(newPanel);
frame.pack();
```

Where *newPanel* contains different objects and layouts when compared to the original *panel*.

But a design problem occurs here. The refresh rate becomes clunky and choppy. Take a look at this *gif* below at my current program:

[image]

You can clearly see the choppy refresh rate between the transition of the original  *panel* and to the *newPanel*.

I got to thinking, maybe it was because I didn't disable the viewing of the frame before packing it. So I then tried:

```
frame.setVisible(false);
frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
frame.getContentPane().add(newPanel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This, however, just yielded the same result as what is presented in the *gif*. I then began googling and found many *StackOverflow* answers saying to either **revalidate()** or **repaint()** the frame before packing. So I tried adding this first in the code right above:

```
frame.revalidate();
```

This didn't work either, whether placed before or after the **pack()** method, yielding the same result. So I tried removing that and tried this in the above code:

```
frame.repaint();
```

That didn't work either, whether placed before or after the **pack()** method, again yielding the same result. So I tried both of them together (before and after just like before) and yet again nothing changed.

I then saw some people recommending this line of code:

```
frame.update(frame.getGraphics());
```

But, again the same result is still presented. I began wondering if it was a problem with **JFrame** and its own internals. So I did an experiment with sleeping the *current thread* right after calling **pack()** but before turning the visibility of the frame to *true*.

This yielded the same outcome. No matter how long I waited, re-displaying the frame to the screen created the same clunky and messy redraw between components as what is presented in the *gif*. Now this is leading me to two possible conclusions, either the **pack()** method is more of a hack than a clean solution or the drawing of the frame to the screen is just buggy in nature with *Java*.

I have tried every method placement I can find. I have experimented many times over again with reorganizing the method calls and I have tried introducing other method calls in hopes of solving this problem.

Has anyone experienced this same result, as every application I have written is subject to this annoyed and ugly design bug. And I just cannot seem to get rid of it.

Is there a solution or do I have to reinvent the wheel with **awt.Panel**?

*-Versions-*

**Java:**

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

(This problem has occurred in previous versions of *Java* for me too)

**MacOS:**

OS X Yosemite

Version 10.10.3

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13 inch, Late 2013)

Here is my output:

[image]

As you can see, I still suffer the same problem as before. In the code I do use **GridBagLayout** but that is not the problem. In the past I have used layouts from **BoxLayout** to **FlowLayout** and I still got the same clunky, messy "refresh" result.

I just tested commenting out portions of the refresh code in my example program like how I did above and again the same result is given. I just provided everything uncommented because no matter what I do with that code, my result is unchanged.

In addition, I can understand downloading a file for some is a problem (e.g. lack of trust in the user) so here is the text:
http://freetexthost.com/rjldye21ix

On a final note, I can post edits with more *gif*s if any new solutions appear.

Comment: No offense, but as a user, switching the screen size like that would give me the s***s, especially because I like to resize most of my windows. Consider having a look at [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for an alternative

Comment: *"I then saw some people recommending this line of code: `frame.update(frame.getGraphics());`"* - Then you should stop listening to them, that is a horrible, horrible idea and would likely cause more issues

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was desperate to try anything. Again, I always try and research my problem before coming onto stackoverflow for help. I find there is always a solution out there for you. This problem just stumps me.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright let me create a runnable example.

Comment: Also, you're obvously running MacOS, which version?  Also which version of Java?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't allow the resizing of my windows currently. I have seen many applications resize the frame for me before and I don't have a problem with it at all. 

See update on java version and MacOS version.

Comment: You're much more forgiving then I am, cause I'd have the app in the bin in a second for just been annoying :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am very curious for your reasons but we can continue that discussion later and not in the comment section.

I just posted a runnable example.

Comment: From what I can tell, `pack` is an expensive call (I mean so is `removeAll`, but), which might have to do with the need for the system to relocate new resources to accommodate the new frame size and because this action tends to occur outside of the EDT, it's possible that there is a race condition between the frame been reallocated space and the repainting occur (this is an assumption on my part). If, instead, I use `CardLayout`, the effect is lessened, probably because I'm seeing a much small change, I can also reduce the effect by removing the call to `pack` each time

Comment: @MadProgrammer I really appreciate `GridBagLayout` as I just switched from `BoxLayout` and `FlowLayout`. That being said, the flexibility and the multi-use of `GridBagLayout` is what I really like. 

Is there another way around this? Is there a way to not call `pack`? I am guessing it would be a more manual approach but maybe through that I can get rid of a possible race case. 

But better yet, what does everyone else do (e.g. professionals)? Obviously people have constructed very fine tune GUIs before. Do others avoid using `pack`? Is this just a *Java* thing, is *C++* better at this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer what do you mean by it "reduce[s] the effect by removing the call to `pack` each time?" CardLayout is just another way of organizing the objects on screen, how do you get out of calling `pack`?

Comment: Well, I'd use a CardLayout to switch between the views. Is it a Java thing? Yes, would c++ Be better? That's debatable, as the code used to generate the native peer and manage the physical frame is likely in C (or ObjectiveC). The problem "might" have be related to the general lack of access to the hardware, everything needs to be done through software libraries (from what I understand), which was the chief compliant by Adobe when Apple complained about Flash

Comment: With CardLayout, you only need to call pack once, you then simply let it do its job of switching out the views. My MiniMac is running at a content 90% CPU usage ATM, running a couple of other Java programs, so, when I was testing CardLayout, I was still able to "see" so, ghosting (but I might have perceived it). Was it Java or was it the OS, I can't tell. What I could tell was, from my observation, it wasn't as bad as having the frame flicking between different sizes. If it becomes a "really" bad situation, you could use a "transition" effect to move from one view to the next